# context:component-scan does not seem to be working (from included jar/package)

Tags: java, spring

I have a project that is using spring just fine to create beans and do component scans of its own classes. I then include a Jar into the build path for another project that I need to add things in for. I can create beans all day, but when I do a component scan it doesn't seem to do anything.

I started with this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.mainPackage.dao.hibernate" />
```

Then changed to this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.mainPackage.dao.hibernate" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.jarPackage.dao.hibernate" />
```

That didn't work so I tried this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.mainPackage.dao.hibernate, com.company.jarPackage.dao.hibernate" />
```

The only errors that display are that my bean cannot be found to do my autowiring. The classes from "mainPackage" can be found, but not from "jarPackage".

All classes in both packages use the @Repository annotation.

I also tried removing the Jar and just including the project directly on the build path in eclipse but that changed nothing.

Obviously the build path is working correctly as i can create individual beans.

```
10:29:14 ERROR - ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(219) | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.company.jarPackage.dao.IGetSomethingDAO com.company.myPackage.service.MyService.someDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.company.jarPackage.dao.IGetSomethingDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.company.jarPackage.dao.IGetSomethingDAO com.company.myPackage.service.MyService.someDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.company.jarPackage.dao.IGetSomethingDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.company.jarPackage.dao.IGetSomethingDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:901)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:685)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 33 more
```

This was in the logs when I turned on spring logging. It's like it's not finding anything...

```
13:14:50 DEBUG - PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(355) | Resolved location pattern [classpath*:com/company/jarPackage/dao/**/*.class] to resources []
```

Comment: can you post your actual error when you have packages in comma seperator

Comment: Added error (edited to remove company specifics). The error is no different from each attempt to fix.

Comment: You are trying to load com.company.jarPackage.dao.IGetSomethingDAO but gave package as com.company.jarPackage.dao.hibernate - remove hibernate

Comment: No change. The interface for the class is in package dao, the implementation is in package dao.hibernate. This is the same way we do it in "myPackage" and that component scan works just fine.

Comment: Added output from log4j showing that it is not finding any resources.